# Infinite authentication loop when using identityserver4 in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Identity Server using identityserver4 framework, its url is http://localhost:9000

My web application is asp.net core 2.0, its url is http://localhost:60002. This application will use the login page of Identity Server.

I want after logging in, the Identity Server will redirect to the application page (http://localhost:60002)

**Here is the Startup.cs of client application**

Startup.cs

```js
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        private string AuthorityUri => Configuration.GetValue<string>("UserManagement-Authority");

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();            

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = AuthorityUri; // "http://localhost:9000"
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = "customer.api";
                options.ClientSecret = "testsecret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.Scope.Add("customerprivatelinesvn.api");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();            

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
```

**Here is the loggin page on Identity Server**

[image]

**But there is an infinite loop that calls to http://localhost:9000/connect/authorize endpoint, and then it returns to http://localhost:60002/signin-oidc with "Bad Request - Request Too Long" as below.**

**When I look at the cookies, there ar lots of items ".AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect.xxx"**
[image]

**Here is the log on Identiy Server. It said that Identiy.Application was successfully authenticated.**
[image]

Does anyone know what this problem is? And how to resolve this? Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Kevin

Comment: Does the error still occur when you remove the line: `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;`?

Comment: Are you including claims with your access tokens?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: This issue was solved after I updated the latest nuget package of IdentityServer4 and .NET Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved after I updated the latest nuget package of IdentityServer4 and .NET Core.

Answer (score 22):

I also had a login loop after copying the startup code from an existing .NET Core 2.2 project and reused it in a new .NET Core 3.1 project.

The problem here was, that the app.UseAuthentication() must be called before the new app.UseAuthorization();

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure

Only in case someone is running into this issue too...

Comment: I ran into exactly this same issue with the same resolution.  Not going to tell you how many hours I wasted on that one.

Comment: You are a champ man! I lost four hours of work to find the problem.

Comment: I have to say thanks too. Been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: I spent the whole day figuring out this. Thanks

Comment: Bless you :) Well spotted. Saved me some hair pulling

Comment: Thank you so much, this saved me quite a headache :)

Answer (score 7):

Adding default Identity in the client app would cause an infinite redirect loop.

In the client app, if you need to use UserManager, RoleManager.

Then use the below code.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Put an end to days of beating my head against a wall!
Do you have any info on *why* this change works? Or somewhere I could go to find it?
Again, thanks!

Comment: AddDefaultIdentity Adds a set of common identity services to the application, including a default UI, token providers, and configures authentication to use identity cookies.

It basically redirects to the authentication server if you visit a protected route but you are already authenticated so the authentication server redirects backs.

Due to this end less loop occurs.

Answer (score 4):

In your client app, in Startup check if you have something like

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Remove that part and try again.

Comment: What if this is needed? I have a "manage authentication application" which has needs to be authenticated using sso.

Comment: This fixed my issue, i was migrating from identity framework to identity server and left the defaultIdentityUI lines.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was missing ***RedirectUri*** when initiating the Signin from the client. Problem solved by adding the RedirectUri as below.

```
 public IActionResult SignIn()
        {

            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, "oidc" );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have a very long request shown there in your Identity Server log - and the error says "Bad Request - request too long". I'd guess that the problem is that your request is too big :)
[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Have you tried posting rather than using a GET?

Answer (score 0):

It happend to me in Azure Portal and IdentityServer4 at the same time.
Cause: I changed the local DATE in my PC in order to test a recurring billing and I forgot it. When I tried to login into Azure portal or into my Identity Server, it entered in a Infinite authentication loop.

Solution: Local PC -> Control Panel -> Date & time settings -> Set time automatically on

I hope it helps